# Page failing to redirect and clearing URL parameters

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, button, mobile-safari

I have a webpage that makes a POST request to a PHP script. Depending on the result of the request, the onclick event for a button sets a redirect to one of two pages.

```
<button id="button" type="submit">Proceed</button>

...

$.post('script.php', {
  key: value
}, function(result) {
  if (result != null) {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
      window.top.location.href = "https://example.com/page?otherkey=othervalue";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
      window.top.location.href = "https://example.com/otherpage?otherkey=othervalue";
    };
  }
});
```

This works fine on desktop browsers, but on Safari on iOS (specifically tested on iOS 10.3.2) upon clicking the button, the page refreshes and doesn't redirect to the correct site. In addition, it clears any URL parameters that were previously there. So for example if the page with the button is `example.com/page?key=value`, the page will refresh and become `example.com/page?#_=_`. I've tried debugging and checking a Javascript console, but it doesn't say anything.

The redirect is a page in my own domain, though the page with the button is integrated into a Facebook app page, if that's relevant.

Also, if I construct the URL on my own and try to go to it normally, it loads fine. I don't know what could cause this, so I'm not sure if there's any other relevant information worth posting, but I can say more if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not deal well with return false being done in the function, and especially with no return at all. I would include a `onsubmit="return function();"` in the html element, which I'm guessing is a form. You also attach this to the submit() event listener via `$('[the form ID]').submit(function(){ do something here; return false;});`

Comment: This didn't quite work to solve my issue, but it did inspire what I figured out to be a solution. I've written another answer, but thank you for responding! :)

Comment: Glad I inspired an idea and sorry it didn't solve the issue directly

Answer (score 0):

I was right that I suppose I didn't supply enough detail, but it seems that because the button in question was inside a `<form>` tag and acting as a submit button, that was messing it up. To solve the issue, I removed the `form` (since I was not submitting any data anywhere, just using the button to redirect the page) and it solved the issue. Now it works on desktop and mobile browsers.